# Accessing functions inside a Ruby block

Tags: ruby, function, hash, scope, private

I'm working inside a one-off Ruby script (so not inside an explicitly defined module or class)  and I'm having a hard time accessing a function I've defined earlier in the script, from within a .each block.

```
def is_post?(hash)
  if hash["data"]["post"] == "true" #yes, actually a string
    true
  else 
    false
  end
end

#further down

threads["data"]["children"].each do |item|
  puts item["data"]["title"] unless item.is_post?
end
```

Result:

```
in 'block in <top (required)>': private method `is_post?' called for #<Hash:0x007f9388008cf0\> (NoMethodError)
```

`threads` is a very, very nested hash. A hash, contaning a hash of arrays, the arrays contain a hash with header data, which contains another hash with the rest of the details. A bit messy, but I didn't write the module that generates that :P

The idea is to iterate through the arrays and retrieve the data from each one.

My questions are:

- What manner of shenaniganery do I need to do to access my `is_post?` function from within the block?
- Why is it coming up as a private method when I don't have any private declarations anywhere in my script?

Comment: You can simplify `is_post?` to just `def is_post?; hash["data"]["post"] == "true"; end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Kernel` vs instance method, `self` vs argument

```
def is_post?(hash)
  ...
end
```

By defining the methods in that way, you are defining a method for `Kernel`. You have the choice of either calling this method through `Kernel.is_post?(hash)`, or `is_post?(arg)`. Unless `item` is the `Kernel` object, you wont have defined the method `is_post?` for it.

Your method takes exactly one argument. In case item has a `is_post?` method, by doing `item.is_post?`, you are not providing an argument but only `self` to the method.

### The solution

You probably should replace

```
item.is_post?
```

by

```
is_post?(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to call `is_post?` on the `item` (it's a `Hash` like the error message says).
What you want is the following:

```
threads["data"]["children"].each do |item|
  puts item["data"]["title"] unless is_post?(item)
end
```